# How to use SUM and GROUP BY function in LINQ

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, c#-3.0

Actually, I am facing a problem in LINQ please help me out in this. Let me share my problem. I have a 2 tables with me.

TABLE1

```
LocationID      LoginID     LocationName
  1               101           A
  2               101           B
  3               101           C
```

In this table we are showing list of location name.

TABLE2

```
ID      LoginID     STOCKID     QUANTITY        LocationID
1         101           1           10              1
2         101           1           -8              1   
3         101           2           20              2   
4         101           2           -5              2   
5         101           1           30              1
```

In this table we are showing the list of quantity of stock item in different location.

Now, I want the result that to show me seperately the total quantity of stock items in each location.
Result Should be like this:

```
LocationID      LocationName        QUANTITY
  1                 A                   32
  2                 B                   15
```

Let me share my code with you.

```
 public ActionResult GetStockQuantityPartial(int? Stock_ID)
    {
        string loginId = Convert.ToString(Session["LoginId"]);

        var emp = (from m in context.StockMovements
                   join o in context.Locations
                   on m.Location equals o.LocationID
                   where m.Stock_ID == Stock_ID && m.LoginID == loginId
                   group new { m, o } by new { m.Location, m.Quantity, o.Location_Name } into grp
                   select new DisplayQuantityViewModel
                   {
                       Location = grp.Key.Location,
                       LocationName = grp.Key.Location_Name,
                       TotalStockQuantity = grp.Sum(x => x.m.Quantity)
                   }).ToList();


        return PartialView("_DisplayStockQuantity", emp);

    }
```

Comment: And what's wrong with your code?

Comment: I m not getting this output

Comment: And what value of `Stock_ID` is passed to the action?

Comment: Table 2 StockId

Comment: `{1, 2}` - which one?

Comment: Stockid 1 actually i want when i pass any stockid in the parameter. I want all location name with their total quantity in list.

Comment: Suppose i pass stockid 1. So in each location stockid 1 quantity calculate. Example      location a  stockid1  quantity10   location b  stockid1  quantity 20

Comment: I do not see `LocationID=2` for `Stock_ID=1` in your sample data...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the issue is that you are grouping on the Location AND the quantity where you only want to group the Movements on the location fields.

```
group m by new { o.LocationId, o.Location_Name } into grp
```

then the SUM line becomes:

```
TotalStockQuantity = grp.Sum(x => x.Quantity)
```

From what I read StockMovement has a Location field, but this is the Location ID. With EF it is beneficial to leverage Navigation properties for FK relationships between entities. This way you can query across these relationships easily and let EF work out the appropriate SQL. This can result in simpler expressions to read from the object graph rather than SQL-like joins.

For instance, instead of this:

```
public class StockMovement
{
    // ... columns...
    public int Location { get; set;}
}
```

... using navigation properties and addressing the assumed column naming in the table..

```
public class StockMovement
{
    // ... columns...
    [ForeignKey("Location"), Column("Location")]
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public virtual Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

This assumes that the column for the LocationId in the StockMovement table is called "Location". Using the `[Column]` attribute or custom mapping (see `EntityTypeConfiguration` for reference) you can configure EF to map fields so your classes can maintain a consistent naming approach even if the tables they reference do not. The same can be done to change "Location_Name" to "LocationName" in the class. You can even do away with the FK column (LocationId) by leveraging `.Map(x => x.MapKey("Location"))` (EF6) or Shadow Properties. (EF Core)

Leveraging the navigation property can simplify the expression to something like:

```
var emp = context.StockMovements
    .Where(x => x.Stock_ID == stockID && x.LoginID == loginId)
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.Location.LocationId, x.Location.LocationName })
    .Select(g => new DisplayQuantityViewModel
    {
        Location = g.Key.LocationId,
        LocationName = g.Key.LocationName,
        TotalStockQuantity = g.Sum(x => x.Quantity)        
    }).ToList();
```

From an object graph / C# viewpoint I find this is much easier to follow than the Linq syntax, so throwing it out there as an option to consider.